# Protobuf grpc_cpp_plugin missing in MSYS2 MinGW packages

Tags: c++, mingw, protocol-buffers, grpc, msys2

I installed a fresh MSYS2 environment, and downloaded the `mingw-w64-x86_64-grpc` package with dependencies ( `mingw-w64-protobuf` is one of them ), and I am able to run protobuf commands except on the grpc_cpp_plugin part. The used commands in the makefile are:

```
GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN = grpc_cpp_plugin
GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_PATH ?= `which $(GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN)`

gen: 
    my_file.proto --proto_path="../proto/" --cpp_out="../cxx/gen/" --grpc_out="../cxx/gen"
```

The exact same commands work from a Debian virtual machine, so it is verified that the command itself should work.

However I get the following error message when I try to generate the files with protoc:

```
grpc_cpp_plugin: program not found or is not executable.
```

I looked at the mingw64 bin folder, and indeed the protoc executable was present, but the grpc_cpp_plugin was missing.

I tried to build grpc from source, but was unabel to make that work, so maybe I thought there is a package I could install to the MSYS environment instead.

I found some executables in another answer, and I copied them, but ( I'm sure because of a version or architecture  mismatch ) those could not be used.

What am I missing? Where can I get the grpc_cpp_plugin executables?

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem of extension resolution under Windows/MinGW.
After the following change to the makefile, the protocol buffers were successfully generated:

```
GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN = grpc_cpp_plugin.exe # . exe was added so the plugin executable would be found
GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_PATH ?= `which $(GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN)`

gen: 
    my_file.proto --proto_path="../proto/" --cpp_out="../cxx/gen/" --grpc_out="../cxx/gen"
```